# Node-based SQL builder with Common Table Expression (WITH clause) support

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm building a Node.js app that needs to query a Redshift database (based on postgres 8.0.2) using CTEs. Unfortunately, the SQL query builders I've looked at thus far ([node-sql](https://github.com/brianc/node-sql), [knex.js](http://knexjs.org) and sequelize) don't seem to support common table expressions (CTEs).

I had great success forming common table expressions in Ruby using Jeremy Evans' Sequel gem, which has a `with` method that takes two arguments to define the tables' aliased name and the dataset reference. I'd like something similar in Node.

Have I missed any obvious contenders for Node.js SQL query builders? From what I can tell these are the four most obvious:

- node-sql
- nodesql (no postgres support?)
- knex.js
- sequelize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use common table expressions (CTEs) with [knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) and it was pretty easy.

Assuming you're using socket.io along with knex.js,

**knex-example.js**:

```
function knexExample (io, knex) {
  io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var this_cte = knex('this_table').select('this_column');

    var that_cte = knex('that_table').select('that_column');

    knex.raw('with t1 as (' + this_cte + 
    '), t2 as (' + that_cte + ')' + 
    knex.select(['this', 'that'])
      .from(['t1', 't2'])
    )
    .then(function (rows) {
      socket.emit('this_that:update', rows);
    });
  })
}

module.exports = knexExample;
```

Comment: I think that example would break if more than one of the component queries (the CTEs and the final `knex.select()`) used bound parameters. Instead of using string concatenation, I'd suggest actually using `knex.raw`'s bindings: `knex.raw('with t1 as (?), t2 as (?) ?', [this_cte, that_cte, knex.select(['this', 'that']).from(['t1', 't2'])])`  Note that this requires knex version 0.8.0, released Apr 30, 2015; also, it triggers knex's "Raw Queries" feature, meaning that "the response will be whatever the underlying sql library would typically return on a normal query".

Comment: Also, see [knex issue #716](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/716) for implementing first-class support for CTEs in knex.

Comment: Concatenating query strings together and using `knex.raw` kinda defeats the purpose of using a query builder in the first place though.

Answer (score 4):

[knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) now supports WITH clauses:

```
knex.with('with_alias', (qb) => {
  qb.select('*').from('books').where('author', 'Test')
}).select('*').from('with_alias')
```

Outputs:

```
with "with_alias" as (select * from "books" where "author" = 'Test') select * from "with_alias"
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1161) and [this issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1077) I understand that you can use CTEs with Sequelize.

You need to use the raw queries and maybe precise the type, to be sure that Sequelize understands it's a `Select` query. See first link.

Sample code would be:

```
sequelize.query(
  query, //raw SQL
  tableName,
  {raw: true, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}
).success(function (rows) {
  // ...
})
```

See [here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/) for mode details.

Answer (score 0):

[xql.js](https://github.com/jsstuff/xql) supports WITH clause from version 1.4.12. A small example:

```
const xql = require("xql");
const SELECT = xql.SELECT;

return SELECT()
 .WITH("with_alias", SELECT().FROM("books").WHERE("author", "=", "Test"))
 .FROM("with_alias");
```

The WITH clause is supported for SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, and compound queries as well.